# Google Maps API for public transports

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

I am not sure this is a proper question to ask here. I am scanning through the Google Maps API, but did not find a obvious way to query for public transit of a specific line.

For example: I want to query for Bus line 545 and get some kind of data like:

```
{
  "Stop":{"Name":"Airport", "Coordinate":"45.00, 45.00", ...}
  "Stop":{"Name":"Downtown", "Coordinate":"46.00, 46.00", ...}
}
```

So I can draw the polyline on map.

I am curious to see if this is possible to get from Google Maps API. If now, is there any recommended data source that I can use? Thanks

Comment: Not with the maps API. Anyway, getting coordinates of the stops wouldn't help much in drawing a route on a map. How do you go from stop 1 to stop 2? You don't know that.

Comment: @MrUpsidown good point! So what option do I have if I want to draw bus routes?

Comment: You have the [Transit layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer#transit_layer) but it's only available in [some cities](http://www.google.com/landing/transit/cities/index.html). Otherwise you will need an external data source. Do you need that for a specific location?